# Declaring a multi-type array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I would like to have my function return an array in which the first element is a String and the second is a UIImageView object. E.g.

```
["An example string", UIImageView()]
```

How do I tell the function that this will be returned in the section that follows the ->

So basically I want a function like this:

```
func DoSomething(num:Int) -> Array[String, UIImageView()] {

    // Each of the following objects in the Array are UIImageView objects        
    Let imageViewObjects = [image1, image2, image3]

    return [String(num), imageViewObjects[num]]
}
```

But the part I know I am getting wrong is the

```
Array[String, UIImageView]
```

P.S. I need to declare this because if I use [AnyObject] it will raise an error later on in the code basically saying that it cant manipulate an object of type AnyObject

Comment: Do you want to return a single `UIImageView` or an array of them? Also, num is an `Int` but you are returning it as a `String`. Which do you want?

Comment: Are you only returning a single set of `String` and `UIImageView`? Why return an `Array` if you're only returning one set of elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that an `Array` is declared as `[Int]` or `Array<Int>` rather than `Array[Int]`. `[Int]` and `Array<Int>` are the same thing. You don't need to use both at once.

The easiest thing to do is use a tuple, declared like this:

```
(String, UIImageView)
```

I would use it like this (your code with corrections):

```
import UIKit
typealias StringView = (String, UIImageView)
// Returning an Optional to pass back that num may be out of range
// note that I'm using the typealias StringView here
func DoSomething(num:Int) -> StringView? {
  let image1 = UIImageView()
  let image2 = UIImageView()
  let image3 = UIImageView()
  let imageViewObjects = [image1, image2, image3]
  // Need to check that num is a valid index
  guard num < imageViewObjects.count else { return nil }
  // return the tuple if num is valid
  return (String(num), imageViewObjects[num])
}
```

Example usage:

```
if let returned = DoSomething(2) {
  // printing the first item in returned tuple
  print(returned.0)
}

// output: "2"
```

You can also use protocols to create a common protocol, add it to the classes in an extension, and then use the protocol in the declaration:

```
protocol Foo {}
extension String : Foo {}
extension UIImageView: Foo {}
var myArray:[Foo] ...
```

If you're going to use the returned value in a lot of places you might want to make it a full-blown `struct` or `class`:

```
import UIKit
struct StringView {
  let string:String
  let view:UIImageView
}

// Returning an Optional to pass back that num may be out of range
// note that I'm using the typealias StringView here
func DoSomething(num:Int) -> StringView? {
  let imageViewObjects = [UIImageView(),
                          UIImageView(),
                          UIImageView()]
  // Need to check that num is a valid index
  guard num < imageViewObjects.count else { return nil }
  // return the tuple if num is valid
  return StringView(string: String(num), view: imageViewObjects[num])
}

if let returned = DoSomething(2) {
  // printing the member "string" in the returned struct
  print(returned.string)
}

// output: "2"
```

A tuple is usually the better choice unless you are using custom structs and classes.

Comment: You can name each element in the tuple like: `(string:String, view:View)` and access it like: `my tuple.string` or just use an index: `mytuple.0` which would be the first element, the `String`. A `typealias` might be nice too: `typealias StringView = (String, UIView)` - then you can use `StringView` wherever you need to declare the tuple.

Comment: @Iso1234 I edited the example to return a single `tuple` rather than an `Array` of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Dictionary objects in swift, here you can use key as your `String` and value as array of `ImageView`

```
let imageViewObjects = [image1, image2, image3]
let array : [String : UIImageView] = [
    String(num) : imageViewObjects[num]
]
```

If you want to return only array you can do like this

```
let imageViewObjects = [image1, image2, image3]
var array : [AnyObject] = [AnyObject]()
array.append(String(num))
array.append(imageViewObjects[num])
```

In this you have to be sure that first object is a `String` and second is array of `UIImageView`